# Как добавить значения в одну таблицу и обновить данные в другой одновременно?

Tags: mysql

связь таблиц

```
workers INNER JOIN reviews_of_workers
ON workers.id = reviews_of_workers.worker_id
```

поля reviews_of_workers, нужен INSERT для них

```
`competence_total` = (@competence_rand := 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4)),
`speed_work_total` = (@speed_work_rand := 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4))
```

поля workers, нужен UPDATE для них

```
`reviews_total` = `reviews_total` + 1,
  `competence` =  `competence` + @competence_rand,
  `speed_work` =  `speed_work` + @speed_work_rand
```

Как правильно написать запрос, чтоб при каждом добавлении строки в `reviews_of_workers`(связанной с  `workers`), на основании вычесленных данных сразу обновить данные в связанной записи таблицы `workers`?

Comment: Запрос ИЛИ вставляет, ИЛИ обновляет. CTE только SELECT, ибо не поддерживает RETURNING. Так что без вариантов - два запроса. Если надо, то в транзакции.

Comment: Думаю вам надо написать триггер на вставку в таблицу, который выполнит update другой таблицы